# Getting Builders Limit Error while deploying on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm getting this error on my vercel CLI when I'm trying to deploy my app:

`Error: Builder returned invalid routes: should NOT have more than 100 properties`

What does this mean? I can't find any documentation for this kindof error. Any idea/help?

Heres the project code: https://github.com/Prottoy2938/vercel-deployment-issue-calcsurf

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation starting on Nextjs 12, the only way to have more than 100 locales or 100 domains is to write custom middleware for routing.

This is the [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#limits-for-the-i18n-config) to the documentation.

Here is a relevant [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28157) raised in the github project of nextjs.